# xcodebuild using wrong provisioning profile

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a bash script where I am trying to automate pushing an IPA to TestFlight. Currently this script is successfully uploading to the app-store with an ad-hoc provisioning profile and not my distribution profile as such I am unable to push the build to TestFlight as it does not have the beta-reports-active key. This is easily fixable from within XCode but I have had no luck using command line which is integral to what I want to do. This is my current command trying to use manual signing:

`xcodebuild archive -workspace $NAME.xcworkspace  -allowProvisioningUpdates -scheme $NAME -configuration Release -archivePath ../builds/$NAME.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=$TEAM_ID CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iOS Distribution: MY_NAME" PROVISIONING_STYLE=Manual PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="PROVISIONING PROFILE "`

Is there a way of getting the correct provisioning profile through command line

**EDIT**
Examples of what I have tried:

- Downloading and inserting the provisoning profile int0 ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ profiles and then using PROVSIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER to point to the profile
- Inserting the app-store method into the export options plist file
- Creating new ExportOptions file that specifies manual signing as well as the provision profile being used - so far getting a signing error due to no provisioning profile being found

Hope this ^ is clear

Comment: Can you show us what you have currently tried to do?

Comment: Edited to try and answer your question, would you like the code ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I was using fastlane to push to testflight and it automatically kept pulling the wrong provisioning profile..

When I dug deeper by running

`xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace Freshdesk.xcworkspace -scheme <My Build scheme>`

I realised that no matter what scheme I picked I kept getting the same provisioning profile in the command line.

I then dug into xcode and chanced on this parameter 
[image]

This was set to staging and I could never sign my app for the app store build, I changed it to production and it fixed my problems

You can find this under "configurations" in the info tab of your project and not the target 
[image]

I hope this helps!